# GDAX C# example

Tags: gdax

https://github.com/dougdellolio/gdax-csharp

I'm trying to get this working but when I try to build it says a few thjings don't exist.

```
Severity    Code    Description                 Project File    Line                                                                        Suppression State
Error       CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  GDAXClient      C:\Downloads\gdax-csharp-master\GDAXClient\Services\AbstractService.cs  70  Active
```

```
if (!httpResponseMessage.Headers.TryGetValues("cb-after", out var firstPageAfterCursorId))
{
    return pagedList;
}

var subsequentPages = await GetAllSubsequentPages<T>(uri, firstPageAfterCursorId.First());

pagedList.AddRange(subsequentPages);

return pagedList;
```

and:

```
Severity    Code    Description                                                     Project File    Line                                                                        Suppression State
Error       CS0103  The name 'cursorHeaders' does not exist in the current context  GDAXClient      C:\Downloads\gdax-csharp-master\GDAXClient\Services\AbstractService.cs  91  Active
```

```
if (!subsequentHttpResponseMessage.Headers.TryGetValues("cb-after", out var cursorHeaders))
{
    break;
}

subsequentPageAfterHeaderId = cursorHeaders.First();
```

I'm very confused...

Answer (score -1):

Solved by using another Gdax C# wrapper. (https://github.com/sefbkn/gdax.netcore)

Got application connected, auth'd, and receiving data.

Cheers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/47552)

Comment: gotta love it. no one answers my question. i found answer to get it working and people here to vote it down.

Comment: This was auto-flagged as low quality, and it is.  Link only answers are petty awful.  At the very least summarize why this fixed things.  If you still don't know...maybe it's not worth posting an answer.